# How can I set the Bing Map style?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, bing-maps

I want to set the map style based on user selection (between aerial, birdseye, road, and streetside) in my Winforms app.

I've got this code:

```
using Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;
. . .

private void aerialToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    userControl11.myMap.Style = Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.aerial;
}
```

...which won't compile, as it tells me:

[image]

I do have Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF in my References.

Also, when I tried this code:

```
this.userControl11.myMap.Style = Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.AerialMode;
```

...I got, "*AerialMode is a type, which is not valid in the given context*"

BTW, I have this for rendering the map control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyMaps.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
   xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF">
    <Grid>
        <m:Map CredentialsProvider="gr8GooglyMoogly" x:Name="myMap" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

### UPDATE

Based on the answer and comments, I am now successfully using these for the three available "modes":

```
this.userControl11.myMap.Mode = new AerialMode(); // Aerial
this.userControl11.myMap.Mode = new AerialMode(true); // Aerial with Labels
this.userControl11.myMap.Mode = new RoadMode(); // Road
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bing/wpf-control/hh709468(v=msdn.10)?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) property and you need to assign a new instance of [AerialMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bing/wpf-control/hh709518(v=msdn.10)?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to it:

```
this.userControl11.myMap.Mode = new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.AerialMode();
```

If you want it to show labels, pass `true` to the constructor of `AerialMode`. You can learn more about map views and modes in: [Understanding Map Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bing/wpf-control/hh830432(v=msdn.10)?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#map-view-modes).

[image]

Comment: Pay attention to the type: `Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.AerialMode`

Comment: Also note that the WPF control does not support Streetside mode. Only the UWP map control and HTML control support Streetside. Birdseye is specific to the HTML map control, while the UWP control supports 3D views (which are like Bird's eye but with full view freedom instead of being locked to just the 4 views).

Comment: Thanks @DuncanLawler, true, I shared link to a [section in documentations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bing/wpf-control/hh830432(v=msdn.10)?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#map-view-modes) which mentions the same: *The Bing Maps WPF Control has three map view modes: Aerial, AerialWithLabels and Road. Road imagery is display by default.*

Comment: UWP map is a choice, if you can accept the limitation: *Windows 10 (introduced v10.0.17709.0) is a prerequisite.*